# Game-like probability problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, markov-chains

I'm quite new to an intermediate study of probability and i would like to ask how this problem can be modeled.

Let's suppose that i have a set of states $(X_{1},X_{2}...X_{n})$ with n given and I know that to reach $X_{2}$ from $X_{1}$ i have a probability $p=0.9$, to reach $X_{3}$ from $X_{2}$  i have a probability $P_{2}=0.4$ and so on until i reach $X_{n}$ from $X_{n-1}$ with some probability $p_{n}$.

If I'm on the state $X_{i}$ and the event "Reach $X_{i+1}$" fails, i have to stay on $X_{i}$ until it succeeds.

Let's suppose that i know $n$ and the transition probabilities of each state, how can i model this problem? markov chain? join of geometric distributions?
What can i say about the final probability to reach $X_{n}$ with some confidence?

(The question may be stupid but i'm interested into sharpening my skills and learning more :) ).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p_i$ be the probability of moving from state $i$ to state $i+1$. The additional time, $T_i$, to reach state $i+1$ given that at a fixed time it is in state $i$ has a Geometric distribution. $P[T_i=t]=(1-p_i)^{t-1}p_i$ because the first $t-1$ units of time must be failures to move to the different state followed by a success. The mean and variance are $\frac{1}{p_i}$ and $\frac{1-p_i}{p_i^2}$. The total time to reach state $n$ is the sum of these independent Geometric random variables.

For example, the density for $T_1+T_2+T_3$ is
$$P[T_1+T_2+T_3=t] \\ =\sum_{n_1=1}^{t-2}\sum_{n_1=1}^{t-n_1-2}P[T_1=n_1]P[T_2=n_2]P[T_3=t-n_1-n_2]$$

$$=\frac{p_1 p_2 p_3 }{(p_2-p_1)(p_1-p_3)(p_2-p_3)}\left((p_2-p_1)(1-p_3)^{t-1}+(p_1-p_3)(1-p_2)^{t-1}-(p_2-p_3)(1-p_1)^{t-1} \right)$$
for $t=3,4,...$.

The sum has mean $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{p_i}$ and variance $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1-p_i}{p_i^2}$. The sum is approximately normal. You can use that to find an approximation for the density or cumulative distribution function. For example, the probability the sum is equal to $t$ is approximately $P[t-\frac{1}2<X<t+\frac{1}2]$ where $X$ is normal with the mean and variance above.